# how to simulate IR vision in Unreal engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, simulation, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, airsim

I am trying to create synthetic data with unreal engine. I want to fly a drone(with AirSim or anything else) and capture IR images.
as its for teaching a neural network, I need a real good IR vision images. I mean just a texture with red color and orange color respecting the corners(like another tutorials in the net) is not as good as I want.
AirSim it self has a IR vision but its something like grayscale and its not good as it should be.
can you please Help me doing this :)?

No difference, UE4 or UE5 or even unity! I just need the simulation (even in paint :D)

I was thinking about setting a variable Temperature for every single object in my scene and using this to convert the RGB to IR but idk it is good or not.
also if you know some material or object available in the market that will capture IR vision images it will be nice if you tell me about it.

[image: its my unreal project]

[image: IR vision image(no matter left one or right one)]

Comment: any idea can be useful :) i have to do it asap so i need your help

Comment: You're looking for a post effect. If you search on google there'll be a bunch of tutorials on creating one - i'm sure you could also find something on the marketplace. You could probably just have the effect always active for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks @George I have searched both google and marketplace but I have found nothing yet... i am steal searching to find some useful thing:)

Comment: I think it depends on what are you trying to achieve. 
If you are trying to classify different objects based on their heat signatures, then it is best to create a realistic heat distribution per object and a post processing shader. 
But if you are trying to detect heat zones, like above a certain threshold, I think you can get away with just using a post processing shader that only looks like a real IR output. 
Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @esgnn yea i want the second one. i just decided to make temperature for every single object and then convert this temperature to IR. thanks for the help

Comment: searching for this too 
@Rezashahriari did you manage to achieve your desired result?

Comment: I hope you realize that your two real example pictures are the _same_ data, with the grayscale one representing the temperatures accurately, and the false-color one merely *illustrating* different levels of temperature more colorfully. false-color isn't data. if you want to train anything, DO NOT give it false-color.

Comment: the least you'll need is ***a texture*** for your deer that represents their surface temperature. you ***cannot*** derive a thermal texture from a deer's "visible color" texture. those things are fairly uncorrelated. get an artist to make that for you from reference pictures. go capture thermal images of captive specimens for best resolution and detail. get all the angles. pretend the deer is going through TSA.

Comment: Id expect you can use a shader that takes greyscale values, and converts from blue to yellow along a gradiant where black is still black but low grey is a blue/purple, through to yellow when its white.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't require *simulation* as such.

This requires you to come up with ***textures*** that represent the temperature (thermal emissions) of the entities you care about. That'll be accurate enough.

All the geometry would just be mapped a texture, but no lighting at all, just texture. Or not even a texture, just a temperature per vertex, for simple objects.

If you want to go overboard, come up with several textures per entity, say one for resting metabolism and one for strenuous activity. Or typical thermal signatures for typical weather patterns and seasons. I'm sure deer vary in that regard. For simple objects, you can skip textures and just give the vertices a temperature. Ground/soil/rocks may be warmer or colder than plants, depending on above-mentioned factors.

Those textures/temperatures ought to be grayscale. Grayscale thermal is data. It's directly related to the actual temperature. False-color isn't data, it's *illustration*. Do not ever feed false-color (illustrations) into any processing.

A deer's visible-color "texture" is fairly uncorrelated with its thermal "texture". You can't take a regular color deer texture and derive a thermal texture from that.

You'll want to get an artist to make up those textures for you. In grayscale of course. You ought to define the scale initially, and adjust any reference pictures to match that scale. Then you can hope to get accurate representations. You should come up with detailed reference thermal images, always grayscale with scale bar, that capture all angles of the model you care about.

Link dump:

- [Texture mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping)

Comment: But I think just texture is not enough or am I wrong? Thermal cameras are just normal cameras sensitive to another wavelength of light. So shouldn't it be a better approach to simulate the heat-signature with the glowing of the objects and capture this? Heat can bounce off like visual light...

Comment: Shit, I just realized that "glowing objects" are just material changes. So my final question would be can we assign a Temp value to an Actor/Object in UE5 and if so, is this possible without changing the "normal" Render image? Because for better training data, RGB + IR would be superior.

Comment: objects in thermal images don't "glow" in any "bloom" kind of sense. there may be a slight blur due to optics/sensor effects. anything "glowing" would be _actual_ radiation, emitted from one object, heating another object. air does not radiate. -- I don't know UE. I know some computer graphics. vertices can be assigned any numbers as attributes, not just "color". that is how you can assign "temperature". then you use that value in the fragment shader to generate an appropriate grayscale (or even false-color) fragment color from the attribute. yes you can assign multiple attributes to a vertex.

Comment: thermal cameras are not normal cameras. the sensor is specially cooled. the lens is a special material. visible light is not let through. the entire infrared spectrum is let through, not just near IR. the sensor measures energy, like any regular image sensor, but its sensor values allow to estimate some object's temperature via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law